# How to let users place content into infowindows Google Maps

Tags: java, android, ios, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

When users create a marker I want them to fill the infowindow with content, mainly an image and adress.

I'm using Google Maps API V2 for Android and Latest version of Google maps SDK for iOS. I'd also want to make sure that only the user themselves can control the content displayed in the infowindow except for reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Let`s Say That your map Connected To web services or Will save On local DataBase ,
So you will need to save Content (String) , Image(URI or URL)

-Then you will need to retrieve Markers Items model from service or Database

-Then you will need to load markers with custom InfoMarker 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#custom_info_windows

Hope that Help

Comment: Thanks but I can't seem to find out how to do it for iOS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267183/custom-annotation-view-in-google-maps-sdk

Comment: For IOS Custom Windows info